# How to make a custom <aui:validator.... to check if the input is not utf-8 , it should show an error message. I am working on liferay and java

Tags: java, liferay

Here is the code - there are many pre-defined validators but I need a custom tag to check if the input is not utf-8 then it should show error

```
<div>
  <aui:validator name="custom" errorMessage="error.message">
             function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
                 var pattern = '/^.*[^\x{00}-\x{00FF}]+.*$/u';
                 return pattern.test(val);
                }
        </aui:validator>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand: utf8 is an encoding, and while in the input field, I'm not aware of them being encoded. Make sure your server and browser communicate with utf8 encoding. No need or option for this in the input field

Comment: sometimes users input some unwanted characters due to which calling to services break down so my task is to force user not to input such kind of characters which are non utf-8